# ClipRRect not working while trying to have rounded edge image

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, widget

below is the code where I want my image to have a rounded edge corner, but it doesn't seem to work. When I use color: Colors.blue, I can see the effect but it is not working as expected for the images. And yeah, i did try using box decoration, that also did not work from me.

```
   class UserAccess extends StatelessWidget {
  List<CardItem> items = [
    CardItem(
      urlImage: 'assets/promise.jpg',
      title: 'Uploads',
      GoTap: ()=> Get.to(JpSelect()),

    ),
    CardItem(
      urlImage: 'assets/promise.jpg',
      title: 'Submit Feedback',

    ),
    CardItem(
      urlImage: 'assets/promise.jpg',
      title: 'Address Book',

    ),


  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.3,
        child: ListView.separated(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          itemCount:3,
          separatorBuilder: (context,_)=> SizedBox(width: 12),
          itemBuilder: (context,index) => buildCard(item:items[index]),
        ));


  }

}
Widget buildCard({
  CardItem item,
}) =>
    Container(
      width: 150,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
               child:
                ClipRRect(
                  borderRadius : BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                    //padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                   child:Ink.image(
                    image:AssetImage(
                        item.urlImage),
                    fit: BoxFit.cover ,
                    child: InkWell(
                        onTap: item.GoTap
                    ),
                  )
                ),

),
          SizedBox( height:6 ),
          Text(item.title)
        ],
      ),


    );
```

Comment: Its working fine for me

Comment: I have updated with the full code. It does not work for me.

Comment: Give your `Container` some background color to see the effect

Comment: yeah adding color, i see the effect but not for the image.

Comment: Well the image is being cut, you might have some transparent background or something. Increase the radius probably

Comment: hey please provide height and width to AssetImage and try..

Comment: i tried with the width and height but did not work.